# Is it possible to implement ros in python GUI using tk

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm creating a GUI for robot operations. I have created one using TK. Now I want to implement ROS to the GUI. Is it possible to implement ros in that python TK GUI program?
Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287339/is-it-possible-to-implement-ros-in-python-gui-using-tk/) by [Nannapaneni](https://answers.ros.org/users/34373/nannapaneni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. If you have ROS installed in the place, where you are going to run Tk program, you can simply use rospy Subscribers to subscribe to topics, where you will get the data.
2. If you want to run the Tk program in an OS, which doesn't have ROS, you can convert the messages to JSON format using [rosbridge_suite](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) and then use generic python packages to convert JSON to be compatible with your Tk package.

---

Originally posted by [Akash Purandare](https://answers.ros.org/users/34280/akash-purandare/) with karma: 61 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0